# spring datasource connection errors

Tags: spring, datasource

Where can I view the datasource connection errors in case configured database does not exist. I was setting up spring security 3.1 to validate using the database with custom schema. Most of the time I spent was due to the typo error in database name in my custom jdbc.properties file.

It would have been much easier had I noticed the error was due to this typo. Is there a way to configure the spring datasource to show the error in case of not able to get the valid datasource connection. One way is to check the returned datasource reference object and determine if it returns null. But basically, I am looking into errors reported by Spring.

```
  //Spring datasource

     <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"> 

        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />  
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="100" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="30" /> 

 </bean>


    <sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
   <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="jdbcUserService"/>
</sec:authentication-manager>


    <beans:bean id = "jdbcUserService" 
    class="com.company.portal.helper.CustomJDBCDaoImpl">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
     <beans:property name="enableAuthorities" value="true"/>
    <beans:property name="usersByUsernameQuery">
        <beans:value>
            select username,password,enabled from users where username = ?
        </beans:value>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="authoritiesByUsernameQuery">
        <beans:value>
            select username,authority from user_roles where username = ?
        </beans:value>
    </beans:property>   
</beans:bean>
```

If this could be achieved using log4j please do explain. I was able to set up log4j for my project modules but not for spring modules. And in case of using new spring modules(e.g.: spring social) would the logging need to be updated?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don`t know any build in way, and it is but it should be easy to implement your own. But instead of invoking the statements, it is much more easieer to invoke the complete`loadUserByUsername` method.

```
@Service
public class StatementChecker implements ApplicationListener<ContextStartedEvent> {

    @Autowired
    private CustomJDBCDaoImpl jdbcDaoImpl;

    public void onApplicationEvent(E event) {
      String username = "iKnowYouExist";
      try {
         UserDetails userDetails = jdbcDaoImpl.loadUserByUsername(username);
      } catch (UsernameNotFoundException e) {
         LOGGER.ERROR ("the user does not exist", e);
      } catch (DataAccessException) {
         LOGGER.ERROR ("some thing is wrong with the query, database or database connetion");
      }
    }
}
```

But to be honest, I strongly believe that **it would be better to write a test case**, maybe you can reuse this code for the test.

Comment: I appreciate your inputs. I will change to a method instead of using statements in xml file for finding usernames. Regarding logging errors, i am looking primarily for built in plug-in type or easily configurable that shows different types of errors as i may not foresee / catch all types of errors if handled manually.

Comment: Spring security is special, it will not leak exceptions to the Frontend because of not leaking security relevant information.